# React text prop linebreak

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I have a prop called data which takes a string as an argument, for example

```
<MyComp 
  data="Some text, some other text"
/>
```

How can I add a line break after `Some text,` let's say? would a simple escaped /n tag work( I mean, is it best practice? )

Comment: you can add `\n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It totally depends on how you are going to use your `data` prop. Escaped Characters (`\n`) will not work in JSX. In this case, I would suggest splitting the lines over multiple props or passing an Array with multiple lines.

However, if you are going to use it for an input element like a textarea, you can use Escaped Characters just fine.

Comment: I splitted /w multiple props

Answer (score 3):

Just use curly braces when passing props and add `\n`:

```
    <MyComp 
      data={"Some text,\nsome other text"}
    />
```

and add css property to element `white-space: pre-wrap;`

Answer (score 2):

You could always have the text be a child prop of your component.

```
<MyComp>
  <div>
    <p>Here I'd like one line</p>
    <p>Here I'd like another line</p>
  </div>
</MyComp>
```

Then in MyComp you can just display it with {props.children}

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to render your text directly, `\n` will not work.

You can for example, add a `<br/>` tag at the end of your rendering function :

```
const MyComp = ({ data }) => <p>{data}<br/></p>
```

And if it is optional, you can add a boolean prop :

```
<MyComp 
  data="Some text, some other text"
  break={true}
/>

const MyComp = ({ data, break }) => <p>{data}{break && <br/>}</p>
```

Another method could be to use nested components, for more flexibility :

```
<MyComp>
    <p>
        Some text, some other text<br/>
    </p>
</MyComp>

const MyComp = ({ clidren }) => children
```

But if you simply want to send this text somwehere else, adding `\n` is alright.

Answer (score 0):

if you want break lines in props you can wrap it in react fragment it will work.

```
<GlobalB
        description={<> <span>Our email management solution is both robust.</span><br/><br/><span>Our platform also enables you to revoke </span></>}
      />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcQ0T.png)